# In order to use a Genasi racial power, must I be in the appropriate manifestation?

Tags: dnd-4e, feats, powers, races

I am a Firesoul Genasi with Extra Manifestation (Water) and Extra Manifestation II (Earth). As I understand it, in order to get the passive bonuses that come with each manifestation (i.e. +1 Reflex and resist fire for firesoul, +1 racial bonus to both Fortitude and saving throws for earthsoul), you must be using that manifestation. Does this also hold true for the racial power (Firepulse for Firesoul, Earthshock for Earthsoul)?

Answer (score 4):

The racial powers and bonuses a genasi gains are a direct result of the *elemental soul* they are manifesting.

Each manifestation has a description of what you gain when using *that* manifestation. Both the passive bonuses **and** the powers are listed in this description so you only gain these benefits if you are using that manifestation.

This is backed up by the fact that the *Extra Manifestation* feat allows you to switch from one to another rather than giving you the benefits of other manifestations in addition to the one you're already using and, as @Oblivious Sage pointed out, the *Double Manifestation* epic-tier feat, which only then allows you to manifest 2 different elements at once so long as you already have access to them (via the *Extra Manifestation* feat).

If merely having access to more than one manifestation allowed you to gain it's benefits, the *Double Manifestation* feat would be unnecessary and/or both of these feats be worded in such a way that told you what extra benefits you would gain.

Comment: To reinforce this point, there is an epic-tier feat, Dual Manifestation, that allows you to manifest 2 different elements at once.

Comment: I was about 95% convinced by this answer. I went and looked at the relevant rules and became 100% convinced by the text of *Extra Manifestation*, particularly the use of the word 'instead' (emphasis mine): "When you take a short rest or an extended rest, you can adopt this new elemental manifestation *instead* of the one you *had been* exhibiting."